# series problem with Battlestar Galactica/Star Trek can someone check my answers

Tags: sequences-and-series

this question is heavily weighted so I am wonder if my answers are correct or if there is a better way to do them.

**Captain Picard and the rest of the crew of the Enterprise are defending their position on the moon
Yavin IV against the evil robotic Cylon invaders. Each day of the battle, 1500 Cylons arrive at dawn,
and throughout the day the crew is able to eliminate 70% of the Cylons on the battlefield.**

**(a) Let Cn be the number of Cylons on the planet at the end of the day on the nth day of the battle.
Find C1, C2, and C3.**

1050(.7)^(n-1)

C1 = 1050

C2 = 1785

C3 = 2299.5

**(b) Find an explicit formula for the number of Cylons at the end of the day on the nth day of the
battle.**

1050(1-.7^n)/(1-.7)

**(c) In the long run, how many Cylons will be on the planet after a day of battle?**

lim n-> inf (1050(1-.7^n)/(1-.7)) = 3500

**(d) If instead the Cylons want to maintain a force of 2000 soldiers, how many should they send each
day?**

600 (by trial and error with calculator)

Comment: I think Cylons are from Battlestar Gallactica, not Star Trek.

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020)'s a tutorial and reference for typesetting math on this site.

Comment: @Michael my bad bro

Comment: @joriki thanks  my homes

Comment: I think this problem wants you to find an expression for $C_{n+1}$ in terms of $C_n$.  You can assume $C_0=0$.  In that case, my reading of the problem is that $C_1=1500(0.3) = 450$.

Comment: How do you get half a Cylon? On second thought, maybe I don’t want to know.

Comment: @amd if u shoot it in the center u kill it but now it's a half

Comment: It’s either dead or alive. Half a Cylon is the same as none in this context. No doubt whoever constructed this problem didn’t consider such niceties.

Comment: @amd i was thinking of it like a penis, can be half erected, or fully erected or flaccid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understood correctly we will at the end of the day have
$$
C_n = 0.30 \cdot (1500 + C_{n-1})
$$
as the crew eliminates $70\%$ of all the Cylons that arrive ($1500$) and all the Cylons that were not eliminated on the previous day ($C_{n-1}$). We use that $C_0 = 0$ and use recursion to compute that
$$
C_n = 1500 \cdot 0.30^1 + 1500 \cdot 0.30^2 + \dots + 1500 \cdot 0.30^n = 1500 \cdot \sum_{i=1}^n 0.30^i
$$
So
$$
\begin{align}
C_1 &= 0.30 \cdot 1500 = 450\\
C_2 &= 0.30 \cdot 450+ 450= 585\\
C_3 &= 0.30 \cdot 780 + 600 = 625.5
\end{align}
$$
The $\sum_{i}^n 0.30^i$ is a geometric series that as $n\rightarrow \infty$  converges to
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} 0.30^i = 0.30 \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} 0.30^i = 0.30 \cdot \frac{1}{1-0.30} = \frac{3}{7}
$$
Such that to maintain a force of $2000$ we would want
$$
N \cdot \frac{3}{7} = 2000 \Rightarrow N = 4666
$$

**In your answers I think you missed an important fact**: It says that $70\%$ are eliminated and thus $30\%$ remain. If it were instead that $30\%$ are eliminated we would have
$$
C_n = 0.7 \cdot (1500 + C_{n-1})
$$
$$
C_n = 1500 \cdot 0.70^1 + 1500 \cdot 0.70^2 + \dots + 1500 \cdot 0.70^n = 1500 \cdot \sum_{i=1}^n 0.70^i
$$
So
$$
\begin{align}
C_1 &= 0.70 \cdot 1500 = 1050 \\
C_2 &= 0.70 \cdot 1050+ 1050= 1785 \\
C_3 &= 0.70 \cdot 1785+ 1785 = 2835
\end{align}
$$
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} 0.70^i = 0.70 \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} 0.70^i = 0.70 \cdot \frac{1}{1-0.70} = \frac{7}{3}
$$
Such that to maintain a force of $2000$ we would want
$$
N \cdot \frac{7}{3} = 2000 \Rightarrow N = 857
$$

Comment: Oh yeah I did an oopsie, I think it should be corrected now.

Comment: hey quick question how did u get 7000 cuz when I try 7000 it gives me 3000 in the long run

Comment: https://www.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/7000%5Ccdot%5Csum_%7Bn%3D1%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%20.3%5E%7Bn%7D

Comment: 7000 is incorrect as you say. It should be 4666. This happened as I forgot to correct the RHS when I corrected the sum on the LHS. When starting on $i=1$ the infiinite sum should be
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} 0.30^i = 0.30 \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} 0.30^i = 0.30 \frac{1}{1-0.30}
$$
and not
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} 0.30^i =  \frac{1}{1-0.30}
$$
as I initially had. I apologize for this.